# Issues with Amazon Cognito and Android SDK NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-asynctask, google-plus, amazon-cognito

I am  unable to authorize with google+ with the Amazon SDK. I can get both a Cognito ID and a Google+ Token, and in my identity pool I can see an unauthenticated user.  In my Cognito setup I have set the server to the right service clientID.

Here's my code:

```
public class cognitoID extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String ... id){
            credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    MainActivity.this, /* Current Activity Context */
                    "us-east-1:XXXXXXXX", /* Identity Pool ID */
                    Regions.US_EAST_1 /* Region */
            );

            credentialsProvider.getCredentials();

            cognitoID = credentialsProvider.getIdentityId();
             Log.i("Cognito", credentialsProvider.getIdentityId());


            if(accessToken =="") {

                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                Log.i("Getting me a token", "allright");

            }
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

                AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());

                android.accounts.Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

            try{
                accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
                scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;
                accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                        getApplicationContext(), accountName, scope);


            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException recoverableException) {
                Log.e("URAE", recoverableException.toString());
                startActivityForResult(recoverableException.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {


                Log.e("GAE", authEx.toString());
            } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                Log.e("IOE", ioEx.toString());
            }
                Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();

                logins.put("accounts.google.com", accessToken);

                credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

                Log.i("everything set", accessToken.toString() + " cognito " + cognitoID.toString());
                credentialsProvider.withLogins(logins);
            credentialsProvider.refresh();

            Log.i("logins", credentialsProvider.getLogins().toString());
            return null;

        }


 }
```

I'm not sure if its my setup on the AWS Developer Console, or whether its the code.

This is the role policy for the identity pools:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Action": [
            "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
            "cognito-sync:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Here are the errors:

Android:

```
03-03 22:41:33.106    1970-2366/com.brillada.comicsareus E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.brillada.comicsareus, PID: 1970
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 5a30d834-c220-11e4-8aed-791c85399196)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:818)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:437)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:243)
            at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:1079)
            at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:499)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:622)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:549)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:499)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:418)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:615)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:549)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:499)
            at com.brillada.comicsareus.MainActivity$cognitoID.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:408)
            at com.brillada.comicsareus.MainActivity$cognitoID.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:352)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't even find where to start troubleshooting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an "Invalid login token" exception from Cognito, which means that the token that you are passing is not valid. This can be mainly due to two reasons:

1. You are passing an expired or null token.
2. You are passing a valid token,but the Google App Id that you are using on your app doesn't match the one you have configured in your identity pool.

Comment: This was it, the client id was from the android app on Google Developer's site and not the service account.

Comment: Hi could you elaborate more on the 2nd issue pointed out please?

Comment: Sure. From the Google console you get an app ID that you have to paste in your app. If you use Google to authenticate your Cognito identities in your app, this same Google app ID needs to also be specified in your Amazon Cognito console in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Javascript passport-google-auth module, it returns access_token, refresh_token, and params.

for getting cognito_identity you need to use params.id_token received from Google

```
 passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(googleDeveloperDetails, getUserDetails));

app.get("/auth/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ['email'] }));

var authGoogle = passport.authenticate("google", {
    failureRedirect: "/auth/google"
});

app.get("auth/google/callback", authGoogle, controller.successRedirect);

getUserDetails = function(accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) {
      if(profile.provider == "google") {
       profile.token = params.id_token   // params.id_token to be used to get cognito credentials
      } else {
            profile.token = accessToken;
      }
      done(null, profile);
}

googleDeveloperDetails = {
    clientID: "google cleint ID",
    clientSecret: "google client secret",
    callbackURL: "https://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback",
    profileFields: ["emails", "profile"]
}
```